# integrating sms-easy to my mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms-gateway

i already know the mailer function in the rails and succeed in sending email to my customer. now im interested in the `smseasy` gem. i have been looking in the internet on how to setup it but i cant find any tutorial. i did read the readme in the https://github.com/preston/sms-easy but i didnt understand it.

```html
# Override the default "from" address with config/initializers/sms-easy.rb
SMSEasy::Client.config['from_address'] = "noreply@example.com"

# Or, you can completely copy sms-easy.yml to your app (http://github.com/preston/sms-easy/blob/master/templates/sms-easy.yml), change it to your liking, and override the default configuration with:

SMSEasy::Client.configure(YAML.load(...))

# Your apps existing ActionMailer configuration will be used. :)

# Create the client
easy = SMSEasy::Client.new

# Deliver a simple message.
easy.deliver("5551234567", "verizon", "Hey!")
```

where does i wrote this code.

if any of you can help to teach me how to setup it. it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The following code belongs in one of your controller actions that you want to trigger sending out the SMS:

```
# Create the client
easy = SMSEasy::Client.new

# Deliver a simple message.
easy.deliver("5551234567", "verizon", "Hey!")
```

under `config/initializers` directory you can create a file called `sms-easy.rb` and put the following line of code to set a from field which is supposed to override the default that you've set up with your mailer settings but it doesn't work for me currently, if i figure it out I can update the answer:

```
# Override the default "from" address with config/initializers/sms-easy.rb
SMSEasy::Client.config['from_address'] = "noreply@example.com"
```